# Divisions for a city?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing (well, still conceptualizing) a fantasy novel and most of the setting takes place in a giant floating city, it is divided into five "islands", each island has a particular use, for example:

- island 1 - residential area;
- island 2 - farms, gardens, water treatment facilities;
- island 3 - electrical grid; etc.

I'm currently using "quarter", I've also thought of using "quadrant", however I'm hesitant to use those words since there are five of these "islands" and both words refer to a set of four. Other words that I've though of using is "district" and "prefecture". Another set of terms that I thought of using is "borough" and "bough" due to the great significance of trees in my world. Bough is also already used elsewhere in my world so this term seems desirable.

Character A explains the divisions of the city to newly-arriving students

> Welcome students to [NAME OF CITY]... [NAME OF CITY] is divided into five [WORD]s, [WORD] 1 is the Air and Seaport, [WORD] 4 is the residential district where you will reside for the duration of your stay and spend most of your time. The Academy is located on [WORD] Alpha or [(initialism of) WORD]A.

Comment: Is it supposed to be a formal administrative division, or just a common name for a part? You can find various subunits used administratively for parts of cities: boroughs, arrondissements, wards, constituencies, parishes, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with island??

Comment: These could be "zones".  Especially if the functions are enforced by law.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/precinct

Answer (score 5):

'Quarters' is fine for 'divisions into which a city etc
is divided', no matter how many there are (within reason).

> **quarter** [noun] ...
>
> 8a: a division or district of a town or city
>
> - *he describes the immigrant quarter* [[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quarter)]

> - The 28 sq km large urban area of Bolzano is subdivided into five quarters around the rivers Adige, Talvera and Isarco. [[Weinstrasse](https://www.weinstrasse.com/en/highlights/town-of-bolzano/the-five-quarters/)]

> The central area of Belfast has been divided into seven Quarters
> related to its history:
>
> - Cathedral Quarter
> - Gaeltacht Quarter
> - Smithfield Market and Library Quarter
> - Linen Quarter
> - Market Quarter
> - Queen's Quarter
> - Titanic Quarter [[Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belfast_Quarters)]

But the final choice is opinion-based.

Comment: There is also a non-fractional use of **quarter** to mean a lodging (often in the plural).

Comment: ... as in the / 2 / 4 / 12 headquarters.

Comment: quarters are attached to something. They are not stand alone entities like in the question (islands).

Answer (score -1):

A [canton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_(administrative_division)) is kind of administrative division popular in Switzerland.